# get data from the api in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit, lazy-loading

I get data from the api in Jetpack Compose but when I try to display it in LazyRow nothing is displayed whereas when I manually feed it, it works fine.

```
             LazyRow(
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 20.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp)
                    ) {
                        professorViewModel.getByUniversityName("universityName") { response ->
                            if (response.status == "OK") {
                                val professorList = response.data!!
                                //During debugging, I see that this list
                                //is correctly filled with two items
                                //and the information is taken from the api and its status is ok.
                                items(professorList.size) {
                                    val professor = professorList[0]
                                    ProfessorItem(professor) //function to show each item
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will show just the first thing because it always shows the element of **index 0**.
A better way to do this is :

```
LazyRow(
         contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 20.dp),
           horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp)
                    ) {                      professorViewModel.getByUniversityName("universityName") { response ->
                            if (response.status == "OK") {
                                val professorList = response.data!!
                                //During debugging, I see that this list
                                //is correctly filled with two items
                                //and the information is taken from the api and its status is ok.
                                items(professorList) {professor->  
                            
                                   ProfessorItem(professor) 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

**Make sure that you're importing the right `items` function because there is two one that takes `Int` as parameter and one that takes `List` as parameter so you import the last one**